# Is it possible to create user account for only can create IPA file but cannot delete or touch anything else?

Tags: ios, ipa, codesign

I know it is awkward question but i cant find certain answer in internet yet. Is it possible to create users in Member Center for people create IPA files on my IOS developer account? But they have to not delete or manage anything else. We need to take some people's projects but don't want to take their codes and run them in Xcode so it would be great if we can get something like IPA file or anything else to only import to devices and run it in legal way. Apple allows that? I am open for any suggestion.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. If the user is only a member, he can't change anything. Only admins and agents can create provisioning profiles etc.

To create users, you have to have a company account.

Comment: thanks for reply but i will have a question, user can do steps for can create IPA file? or admin should create profiles for member?